# Nunit System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity System.Xml.XmlException: Object type is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nunit

I am getting this error when testing C# dll using Nunit 2.6.2.

```
System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
System.Xml.XmlException : Object type is not supported.
```

Plz have a look.

Comment: At least give us the line of code that throws the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofObjectToReturn must be a `Stream` type

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.getentity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Exceptions :
>
> XmlException  : ofObjectToReturn is not a Stream type.